# Exponential backoff for AWS Lambda Asynchronous Invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

AWS Lambda's [Asynchronous Invocation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) states that

> For throttling errors (429) and system errors (500-series), Lambda
> returns the event to the queue and attempts to run the function again
> for up to 6 hours. The retry interval increases exponentially from 1
> second after the first attempt to a maximum of 5 minutes.

I'm trying to understand what "The retry interval increases exponentially" means **exactly**.  Does it go from 1 second to 3, to 7?  I'm unable to find any specific information on this anywhere on Lambda information pages.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind an exponential backoff (with retry) is that the retry interval increases *exponentially* between retries after each failure.

In this case, the documentation is just specifying the minimum and maximum for the retry interval. This means that the initial retry delay is 1 second and the maximum retry delay is 5 minutes.

The retry delay will not be increasing beyond 5 minutes regardless of if Lambda failures are still occuring.

Something like the below, is how this works:

```
1. Try to process request
2. Request returns 429 or 5xx
3. Wait 1 second
4. Retry
5. Request returns 429 or 5xx
6. Wait 2 seconds
7. Request returns 429 or 5xx
...
43. Wait 5 minutes
44. Request returns 429 or 5xx
45. Wait 5 minutes
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers my question.  I'm confused with what exponential backoff is - and even have an example of an example of a 0, 1, 3, 7 exponential rate of 2 in my question.  I also understand that the delay saturates at 5 minutes and starts at 1 second.  However, there are different ways to implement this - it could be 1, 2, 4, 8, it could be 1, 5, 20, 80 based on what the exponential rate is.  My question is what the exponential rate is defined at, as this information seems not be defined anywhere.

Comment: It’s 1, 2, 4, 8, 16… as I’ve clarified in my answer.

Comment: How do you know this?  Does it appear somewhere in their docs?  Have you tested this empirically?

Comment: @MichaelLee It doesn't mention it explicitly but you can practically try it out. They assume common knowledge of an exponential rate of 2 if nothing else is specified.

Comment: @MichaelLee Did you test it? :)